# how to make api call complete before moving to another task in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using angular 2 with ionic 2. I am calling an api which is completely not return data, it starts another task. How to make call completely finish before it goes to next step.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AbsconderService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AbsconderService Provider');
  }

  getAbsconders() {
        var url = 'http://someservice/admin_backend/public/Api_abscounders';
        var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
        return response;
    }

}
```

**in Controller**

```
getData() {
    this.absService.getAbsconders()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.Records = data;
        console.log(this.Records.data);
      })
  }

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Absconders');
    this.Records = this.getData();
    this.setFilteredItems(); // before above call finishes, this run in between and then again this.getData() is filling this.Records


    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, move the code to within the subscribe:

```
getData() {
    this.absService.getAbsconders()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.Records = data;
        console.log(this.Records.data);
        this.setFilteredItems();   //<- Moved it here.
      })
  }
```

That way it will not execute until the call is complete.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little short

```
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
```

`this.http.get(url)` is probably an async call.  In which case you will probably need `.then` or a callback before you can put it through the `map`.

Comment: .then does not exist in Observable

Comment: In that case maybe you need pass a callback `this.htp.get(url, function(ret) {})`, or something similar.  Somehow you have to wait for the AJAX call to complete.

Comment: is this necessary when I am using .subscribe at controller end ?

Comment: @Mangrio I think you are right.  `.map` following `.get`  looks like a viable option.

Comment: any idea, why I am not getting data before next statement ?

Comment: sorry, but I can't see it. I am not that familiar with Observable.  The only think I would suggest (and it is a long shot at best) is to try this `this.http.get(url).toPromise().then( resp => console.log(resp))`, but as I say it is a shot in the dark.